# Dynamically change div background in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I know that I can change the CSS of a div with the following:

```
MyDiv.CSSClass = "MyClass"
```

However, what I am trying to figure out is how to dynamically grab a Div and then do this.

I have a function that gets called a bit and will change the background color of the div based upon the resulting value (integer).  The function is like this:

```
Public Sub ReadValue (Tag, DivID)
```

I am passing in the ID of the Div into the DivID parameter.  Since that is a string and not an actual object, how would I then change the class??

I'm fairly confused :)  It seems like it would be easy, but I can't find anything on the internet to help me figure it out.

thanks in advance.

---

Here is the actual code:

Code of Stylesheet:

```
.container {width: 100%;
background: transparent;
max-width: 1000px;
min-width: 1000px;margin:0 auto;min-height: 200px;}
.table-left{
float:left;
width:400px;
border: 1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;
}
.mtable-left{
float:left;
width:299px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
min-height:50px;
}
.mtable-left-right{
float:right;
width:100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
min-height:50px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
.table-right{
float:right;
width:400px;
border: 1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;
}
.legend-left{
float:left;
width:550px;
border: 1px solid #000;
min-height:100px;
}

.mlegend-left{
float:left;
width:299px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
min-height:30px;
text-align:center;
}
.mlegend-leftc{
float:left;
width:99px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
min-height:30px;
text-align:center;
}
.mlegend-leftv{
float:left;
width:150px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
min-height:30px;
text-align:center;
}

.arges {clear:both;}
.yellow{background:yellow;}
.red{background:red;}
.blue{background:blue;}
.green{background:green;}
.gray{background:gray;}
```

HTML Code

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="index.aspx.vb" Inherits="overheads_default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="styletest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="True" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Timer ID="tmrRefreshSchiwaStatus" runat="server" Interval="30000">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:Timer ID="AlertRefresh" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="false"></asp:Timer>    
<div class="container" runat="server">
<div class="table-left" runat="server">
   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server">Status</div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">Conv. Sys 1A</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right gray" id="Status1" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">SRM 61</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right red" id="Status2" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">SRM 62</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right yellow" id="Status3" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">Conv. Sys 1B</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right green" id="Status4" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">SRM 63</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right red" id="Status5" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left" runat="server"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right" runat="server"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left" runat="server">SRM 64</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right blue" id="Status6" runat="server"></div>


</div>
<div class="table-right">
<div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right">Status</div>
<div class="mtable-left">Layer Picker</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right gray" id="Status7" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left">Wrapper 1</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right red" id="Status8" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left">Wrapper 2</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right yellow" id="Status9" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left">Wrapper 3</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right green" id="Status10" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left">T-Car</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right gray" id="Status11" runat="server"></div>

   <div class="mtable-left"></div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right"></div>

    <div class="mtable-left">Spare</div>
   <div class="mtable-left-right red" id="Status12" runat="server"></div>

</div>
<div class="arges"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<b>Legend</b>
<br/>
<div class="legend-left">
    <div class="mlegend-left">Tag Value</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftc">Color</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftv">Desc.</div>

    <div class="mlegend-left">1</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftc yellow"></div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftv">Idle</div>

    <div class="mlegend-left">2</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftc green"></div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftv">Running</div>

    <div class="mlegend-left">3</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftc blue"></div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftv">Faulted</div>

    <div class="mlegend-left">4</div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftc gray"></div>
    <div class="mlegend-leftv">Manual/Maint.</div>





</div>
<div class="arges"></div>




</div>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>      
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition, I have tried the following code:

```
Status3.Attributes("CSSClass") = "mtable-left-right blue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a string ID you can pass actual control, e.g. if you define your sub as

```
Public Sub ReadValue(Div As WebControl)

    Div.Attributes("class") &= " MyClass"

End Sub
```

You can call it as

```
ReadValue(MyDiv)
```

Or if you prefer - you can pass an ID to sub defined as

```
Public Sub ReadValue(DivId As String)

    Dim Div As WebControl = FindControl(DivId)
    Div.Attributes("class") &= " MyClass"

End Sub
```

Here you using `FindControl` function to locate DIV by ID, so you can call it

```
ReadValue("MyDiv")
```

Note that if your DIV is located inside of a container control - you may use an alternatice `FindControl` call that indicates level of nesting e.g. `FindControl(DivId, 1)`

Comment: I am trying that, but it doesn't seem to be having an effect :(  I have tried calling them directly even, but the color isn't changing.  I am using AJAX (UpdatePanel). Do I have to postback to get color to change?  I know I can change images and text without postback.

Comment: Does your original test code `MyDiv.CSSClass = "MyClass"` works? If the DIV is inside of update panel and is a part of partial postback - the color change should work

Comment: MyDiv.CSSClass = "MyClass" does not work.  Div is inside the updatepanel and is inside a form with EnablePartialRendering=True.Also - div is runat="server"

Comment: Can u verify that "MyClass" has the colors you need - can you post its CSS definition in your original post?

Comment: yes... I simplified it a bit, so will have  to post what it actually is :)

Comment: ok, added CSS and HTML.  Should show you what I am doing.  I am only trying to update the CSS for the div's with IDs 'Statusxx'  (where xx= 1 to 12)

Comment: Also added what I tried to do direct change of css.  That didn't work either :(

Comment: What's causing Panel to update - timer or some other control? Are u placing your color changing code into event of that control? does other code (to change text etc.) in the same place work?

Comment: Yes, there is a 30 second timer (asp.Timer) which is running the code to change CSS. Yes, text will change if I use asp:label.

Comment: Changed HTML to add    <asp:Label ID="lblStatusName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> then added    lblStatusName.Text = "System 1A" and it worked no problem that way.  But that is an asp label control as opposed to an HTML element.

Comment: Try this: `MyDiv.Attributes("class") &= " myClass"`

Comment: so simple.  thank you, please put that in y our post above and I'll accept it as the answer.